# How to assign values to a two dimensional dynamic array?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I found that the problem is segmentation and the program receives a signal SIGSEGV.
The program is much more complicated than this but these are the only points these arrays are affected.

**When trying to print or assign values to the Inputarray and Outputarray the program crashes without showing any errors.**

I created a program that does only that and it works just fine, therefore since I had no idea what causes this problem I decided to put all the code up to that point.

*THE PROGRAM CRASHES AT THE LOOP IN WHICH I HAVE INCLUDED THE EXCLAMATION MARKS.*

Up to that point it works fine. When I looked for similar cases all I found is people using different functions to allocate their arrays which I don't understand how it relates to my problem. The weirdest thing is that I created another program with just this and it seems to work Thank you for the help!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    FILE*Results_ptr;
    int* WaveguideConfig;
    double* itta;
    double** InputArray;
    double** GateArray;
    double** OutputArray;
    double** ProbabilityArray;
    double Final[21];
    double Error, ErrorIncrement;
    double j,G,LO;
    int* PhotonArray;
    int i,m,z,o,k,a,c,v,I,M,A,B,C,D,E,F,H,J,K,N,NP,W,V,Z,L,GP,U,WG,ii,jj;

    printf("Enter an integer for the number of entry points:");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    printf("Enter an integer for the number of waveguides:");
    scanf("%d",&WG);
    printf("Enter number of photons:");
    scanf("%d",&NP);

    WaveguideConfig=(int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
    itta=(double*)malloc(N * sizeof(double*));
    InputArray=(double**)malloc(NP * sizeof(double*));
    OutputArray=(double**)malloc(NP * sizeof(double*));

    for(W=0;W<NP;W++)
    {
        InputArray[W]=(double*)malloc(N * sizeof(double));
        OutputArray[W]=(double*)malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    }
    GateArray=(double**)malloc(N * sizeof(double*));
    ProbabilityArray=(double**)malloc(N * sizeof(double*));

    for(Z=0;Z<N;Z++)
    {
        GateArray[Z]=(double*)malloc(N * sizeof(double));
        ProbabilityArray[Z]=(double*)malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    }

    Results_ptr=fopen("Results.txt","w");
    printf("Enter configuration of the waveguides:");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &WaveguideConfig[0], &WaveguideConfig[1], &WaveguideConfig[2], &WaveguideConfig[3], &WaveguideConfig[4], &WaveguideConfig[5], &WaveguideConfig[6]);
    printf("Enter the corresponding values of reflectivity:");
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf",&itta[0],&itta[1],&itta[2],&itta[3],&itta[4],&itta[5],&itta[6]);
    PhotonArray=malloc(NP * sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter photon entry points:");
    scanf("%d %d", &PhotonArray[0], &PhotonArray[1]);
    printf("Enter error in reflectivity:");
    scanf("%lf",&Error);
    ErrorIncrement=Error/10;

    for(H=0;H<10;H++)
    {
        for(GP=0;GP<NP;GP++)
        {
            InputArray[GP][PhotonArray[GP]]=1;
        }
        C=0;
        E=0;
        C=0;
        G=0;
        for(k=0;k<WG;k++)
        {
            for(m=0;m<N;m++)
            {
                for(z=0;z<N;z++)
                {
                    if(z==m)
                    {
                        GateArray[m][z]=1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GateArray[m][z]=0;
                    }
                }
            }
            GateArray[WaveguideConfig[k]][WaveguideConfig[k]]=sqrt(itta[k]+H*ErrorIncrement);
            GateArray[WaveguideConfig[k]][WaveguideConfig[k]+1]=sqrt(1-itta[k]+H*ErrorIncrement);
            GateArray[WaveguideConfig[k]+1][WaveguideConfig[k]]=sqrt(1-itta[k]+H*ErrorIncrement);
            GateArray[WaveguideConfig[k]+1][WaveguideConfig[k]+1]=-sqrt(itta[k]+H*ErrorIncrement);
            for(I=0;I<N;I++)
            {
                for(M=0;M<N;M++)
                {
                    if(M==(N-1))
                    {
                        if(I==(N-1))
                        {
                            printf("%lf\n\n", GateArray[I][M]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("%lf\n", GateArray[I][M]);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("%lf\t", GateArray[I][M]);
                    }
                }
            }
            for(L=0;L<NP;L++)//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            {
                for(i=0;i<N;i++)
                {
                    for(o=0;o<N;o++)
                    {
                        OutputArray[L][i]+=GateArray[i][o]*InputArray[L][o];
                        printf("%lf", OutputArray[L][i]);
                    }
                }
            }//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!`
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First step of programming is to learn how to indent your code.

Comment: First step with dynamic memory allocation is not to cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C. This is not C++! And: these are no 2 dimensional arrays, but 1D arrays of pointers (to 1D arrays).

Comment: Run this code through a debugger - single step and then you will see where's it's 'crashing'. Also - split the code into functions - so it's not so 'hairy' to look at.

Comment: I would also look at the output produced by the application - that might at least give you a hint as to what is going wrong. you can add extra debug this way to trace what is happening.

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

before posting a question.

Comment: @Neil I tried to debug it and I'm getting a segmentation error. When I look up solutions all I get are vague answers and have no idea how to counter it. Sorry about the formatting error, I don't have much of a background in computing, I just use it it for physics. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I see no errors in the loop. All arrays accessed are properly allocated and have the right size.

However, the return value of scanf is never checked and not reading an expected value can result in using an unitialized variable (with random value).

Use:

```
    printf("Enter an integer for the number of entry points:");
    if (scanf("%d",&N) != 1) {printf("Invalid input\n"); return(1);}
```

I am not a scanf guru but often see the use of a leading space to skip any white space still in the buffer:

```
    printf("Enter an integer for the number of waveguides:");
    if (scanf(" %d",&WG)!=1) {printf("Invalid input\n"); return(1);}
```

**EDIT**
..neither is the return value from `malloc` checked. Hence, using an unitialized variable (because `scanf` failed) with an unexpectedly large and random value, will let `malloc` fail because too much memory is requested. As a result, I expect that during your loop memory that is not of the program is accessed, which the memory manager flags as illegal and aborts the program.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I see is this:

```
printf("Enter an integer for the number of entry points:");
scanf("%d",&N);
...
WaveguideConfig=(int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
itta=(double*)malloc(N * sizeof(double*));
...
printf("Enter configuration of the waveguides:");
scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &WaveguideConfig[0], &WaveguideConfig[1], &WaveguideConfig[2], &WaveguideConfig[3], &WaveguideConfig[4], &WaveguideConfig[5], &WaveguideConfig[6]);
printf("Enter the corresponding values of reflectivity:");
scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf",&itta[0],&itta[1],&itta[2],&itta[3],&itta[4],&itta[5],&itta[6]);
```

You specifically read in 7 array values for both `WaveguideConfig` and `itta`, however if you enter a value of `N` less than 7, you're not allocating enough memory for for those arrays and writing past the end of allocated memory.

Next is this:

```
printf("Enter number of photons:");
scanf("%d",&NP);
...
PhotonArray=malloc(NP * sizeof(int));
printf("Enter photon entry points:");
scanf("%d %d", &PhotonArray[0], &PhotonArray[1]);
printf("Enter error in reflectivity:");
....
for(H=0;H<10;H++)
{
    for(GP=0;GP<NP;GP++)
    {
        InputArray[GP][PhotonArray[GP]]=1;
        ...
```

If you enter in a value for NP greater than 2, only the first 2 items in `PhotonArray` are initialized.  So once `GP` is greater than 1, `PhotonArray[GP]` is undefined and so `InputArray[GP][PhotonArray[GP]]` could point past the end of the array.

There's more going on than this as well.  Run your code through valgrind, and that will tell you when you're overstepping your memory bounds.

Comment: I always use numbers that don't overstep the memory bounds cause this is a test. When the program is finalised it will be an fscanf function reading from a file. However, I want to get this to run first, until that point, I'm careful to use correct numbers.

Comment: Still, run your code through valgrind.  That will tell you where you're overstepping your memory bounds.